# blogger.com function load uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, blogger

My javascript is loaded before  on a blogger template here: http://fashioncherry.blogspot.no/ I've also tried to make sure it is only loaded once by adding the code:

```
function loadAdlinkAd(){
  if( !adlinkAdLoaded ){
    adlinkAdLoaded=true;
```

Before the post footer () I've added the code:

```
<a class='adlink-stylemag-btn' href='http://stylemag.no'> <img alt='stylemag' height='150' src='http://adlinkmedia.no/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/STYLEmag_knapp_150x150.png' width='150'/> </a>
<script type='text/javascript'>loadAdlinkAd();</script>
```

I tried the same thing on http://www.camillaabry.com/ and it worked great there. So I cannot understand why I get the uncaught referenceerror $ is not defined. I'm also a newbie when it comes to this, so I'm not sure how to fix it...:-(

Answer (score 0):

$ is the variable jQuery is normally stored under. Include the jQuery library before you initialize the code that throws the error and it will probably work fine.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```